# Where can I find more infomation on wxPython's Fancytext?

Tags: python, text, wxpython

I'm trying to write a scientific calculator application for a school project and I want to use Fancytext to display the numbers/results, but I don't understand exactly how fancytext works. Is there a place with a good tutorial or documentation that I can look at? Or can someone give me a quick run-through? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation pages for FancyText at the following:

- http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.fancytext-module.html
- http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/Phoenix/lib.fancytext.html

I would also recommend downloading the wxPython demo package from their website. There's a good demo that shows how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use wxPython before. But ,by google, I got [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/128350/starting-wxpython-gui-code/2#post643697).Maybe help you.